# What is the correct process for primer on new plaster?

Tags: painting, plaster, primer

The guidance for the paint we’ve bought says we should use a primer on our new plaster (rather than a mist coat of emulsion paint).

- Should I apply the primer as is or does it need to be watered down?
- If so, what ratio of primer to water should I use?

Comment: What does the can of primer say about applying it to new plaster? I'd guess that it's "apply". Follow the directions on the tin.

Comment: This should be asked of the supplier of the paint/ primer.  The manufacturer has the last say on how their product should be used. If not on the can, there should be a customer service number or website you can refer to.

Comment: If you haven’t bought the primer yet, look for one that’s labeled for new plaster.

Comment: Hi all, thanks very much for the replies. I've bought 'GoodHome White Wall & ceiling Primer & undercoat' – on the tub it says 'suitable for use on bare plaster', so I assume this is okay for new plaster. Just would like to know if it would be best practice to water down the first coat at all? Link to the primer here:

https://www.diy.com/departments/goodhome-white-wall-ceiling-primer-undercoat-10l/5036581057077_BQ.prd?alt=true